# There is no continuous functional $T:L^p(\Omega)\rightarrow L^p(\partial \Omega)$, with $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$? (As in trace theorem)

Tags: partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, trace-map

Why it is not possible to define a continuous functional such that
\begin{equation}
 \begin{split}
  T\colon L^p(\Omega)& \rightarrow L^p(\partial\Omega)\\
 u&\mapsto Tu=u_{|_{\partial \Omega}}\\
 \end{split}
\end{equation}?

MY ATTEMPT:
Since $C_{0}(\Omega)$ is dense in $L^p(\Omega)$. I defined $u_m=\frac{1}{1+m\; \mathscr{d}(x, \partial \Omega)}\in C_o(\Omega).$ That is a sequence in the subset of continuous functions with compact support. It is known $\partial \Omega$ we have $u_m=1$, also $0\leq u_m\leq 1\in \Omega$, that is $u_m\to 0$ a.e. $\in \Omega$.

Then if is considered that this functional exists (as in trace theorem), hence considering dominated convergence theorem, one can write
$$\|Tu_n\|_{L^p(\partial \Omega)}\leq C\|u_n\|_{L^p(\Omega)}\to 0$$

However, is a contradiction since $Tu_n=u_n=1\; \forall x\in \partial \Omega$. Therefore this operator does not exist.

MY DOUBT: Do I really need to prove that, or if I say that there is no weak derivatives in the domain (that is, $L^p(\Omega)$) is that enough?

Comment: Your attempt is fine. This is the proof. The argument in the last sentence makes no sense. Non-existence of weak derivatives is unrelated to the statement you wnat to prove.

Comment: @daw thanks, I only asked because of the construction of the proof of trace theorem. I mean that,  the inequality was obtained through embedding of  $W^{1,p}(\Omega)$ (where we do have weak derivatives) into $L^p(\partial\Omega)$. That's way I am in doubt.

Comment: So, what is the importance of weak derivatives in the proof of Trace theorem?